# Is exclusive-or more computationally expensive than other logical connectives? (Related: it's also the only one that optimally preserves data.)

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, computational-complexity, boolean

I expect this will be a very easy question to ask and answer. I noticed that `XOR/XNOR` *seem* to have a property I don't see in any other binary Boolean operation: in the general case, you need to know the values of both inputs to yield an output.

This is in contrast to, I believe, every other binary connective. For `AND`, if one of the inputs is false, the output is false, and all things being equal, you'll only have to check both inputs half of the time. Similar logic holds for `OR`, `NAND`, `NOR`, and `IMPLIES`.

In the real world, I know sometimes this makes no difference, particularly if you're talking about a certain physical circuit or something where all the work will always get done regardless. But certainly the general behavior in the computer science world is that once any of the inputs force a certain result on a logical operator, the computations intended for any remaining inputs are discarded, where possible.

The bottom line is that for `XOR/XNOR`, it seems like barring simplification, you must always carry out $2$ "units" of computation, one for each input, while for everything else, you'll only need $1.5$ units of computation on average. Even if the inputs aren't so well-distributed, `AND/OR` et al only pull even with `XOR/XNOR` in the absolute worst case.

I know this is a very minor thing, I'm just surprised I've been doing math/CS for so many years and I've never seen it come up. Basically, all I'm looking for is some confirmation of this property; if anyone can explain why it does or doesn't matter for e.g. low-level optimization tasks, I would be interested to hear that too.

Of course, if I've got something wrong here, please explain my error and I'll accept that as an answer too.

---

For what it's worth, I ran a quick spot check in Mathematica, one that barely involves computation, just a random element selection. Results below, where numbers given are seconds elapsed per operation (after running each function repeatedly for ten seconds).

[image]

---

**Response to a couple comments below:**

Loosely related to this observation is the property of `XOR/XNOR` wherein they perfectly transmit information, inasmuch as a 2-to-1 gate can. No other 2-to-1 gate does this. They all destroy information.

(Assume well-distributed random inputs for the following.)

Every output bit you get from an `XOR` gate eliminates precisely 2 of the 4 possible input pairs, on average. If you could then see one of the input bits, you would ascertain the other input with certainty. (This is essentially how [RAID 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5) and similar tricks work; you can have two drives worth of data saved across three drives, all `XOR`ed, and any drive can be replaced with no data loss.)

Whereas if you have a `NAND`, $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time its output would be $0$, telling you its inputs are exactly $(1,1)$. The other $\frac{3}{4}$ of the time, the `NAND` output would be $1$, which only tells you the inputs aren't both $1$. If you go on and examine one of the input bits, half the time it would be it would be $1$, implying the remaining bit is $0$; the other half it would be $0$, giving you no information about the remaining bit, which would then need to be checked as well.

So the number of bits you need to inspect (if you start with the output) to know the full state of the `NAND` gate is, on average, $$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1+\frac{3}{8}\cdot 2+\frac{3}{8}\cdot 3 = \frac{17}{8} = 2.125.$$

Compare to the `XOR` case, which is always simply $2$ bit checks required, since any two bits determine the third.

So yes, while `XOR` isn't functionally complete like `NAND`, it is more expressive in the narrow sense that it's an inherently cleaner transmitter of information. (Incidentally, discarding or disregarding data actually seems to be a fundamental requirement to enable full Turing-complete computation.)

Comment: I imagine it doesn't matter because of the underlying logic gates/transistors. Also, the ```AND``` of two boolean expressions that need to be evaluated has a different interpretation than the ```AND``` of two bits, so that could be another reason.

Comment: Even if there were a difference in performance, it doesn't really matter because the choice of operator is dictated by the problem you're trying to solve. It is meaningless to compare the performance of `a AND b` with `a XOR b` because they do totally different things.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's meaningless, it means it's more complicated than just saying one will always be faster than the other, which I wasn't claiming.

Comment: You can express all the Boolean operators with NAND. You can do the same with NOR. So XOR is definitely not the most expressive gate.

Comment: Yes, of course XOR is not functionally complete on its own. In one sense, though, XOR/XNOR *is* the most expressive gate, being the only binary one that doesn't discard information. You learn more, on average, about the probability distribution of the input bits when you see an XOR output than when you see any other gate's output.

Comment: XOR tells you the correlation of the two inputs but nothing about their individual values, because 1 XOR 1 = 0 XOR 0.

Comment: xor does destroy information, unlike for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate

Comment: The interesting thing about XOR is that it's bidirectional. All of these binary operators involve three values: two in, one out. With XOR you just need to know any two of those to deduce the third. With NAND you can also deduce the third value from two others in general, but only if the two others are the inputs.

Comment: To use XOR in cryptography, let one input be the message and the other input be a stream of random, uncorrelated bits. The output then is also a stream of random, uncorrelated bits containing no information for any attacker. But if you know the random input you can extract the original message. That is, you can use a random string of bits as a one-time pad.

Comment: In computing, I'd expect the timing would be determined by the need to have both inputs present in registers on one clock cycle and the output present in a register on another clock cycle. All these operators take relatively simple logic so I'd expect them all to be equally fast. But I think it is true that the XOR generally takes more transistors than the others; see, for example, https://eepower.com/technical-articles/basic-cmos-logic-gates/. You could use that as a measure of "expense".

Comment: XOR requires 8 transistors using CMOS tech doing it the standard way, which is way more than other 2 input gates.  But IBM found a way to make an XOR using only 6 CMOS transistors in an unconventional way that breaks a lot of layout designers.